# Why do my particles keep spinning after hitting a collider?

Tags: particles, physics, collision

[image]

I want to make an animation where bullet casings are ejected from a rifle, spins mid-air, hits the ground and eventually stops moving. The casings bounce properly, but their angular momentum is not lost and they keep spinning long after hitting the collider. I tried the die on hit and render dead particles method but that doesnt look great. Is there any way to make them lose their angular momentum over time?

Floor collider settings

[image]

Casing particle settings

[image]

Comment: A particle system emits points. These points will be used for collision, even if you choose to 'render' a bullet shell onto each point. There is no way to have more complex collision shapes inside a particle system (yet / afaik). 
This is the reason why your shells will continue to spin like small planets, regardless of their shape. On a point, there's simply no 'lever' to apply a counter-force to the initial spin. Hope this makes sense... You could try a rigid body sim. Or python. :-)

Answer (score -1):

May not fit your exact requirements if you're trying to be very specific about the trajectory of the casings, but building on @LazerLars comment you could render as an object with a rigidbody or even a collection if you wanted to make unique casings with different imperfections. If the rendered object has a rigidbody attached, each particle will instantiate a new duplicate object with an attached rigidbody and become part of the rigidbody simulation. Then coupled with your initial velocity, when you bake all dynamics you'll get proper physics and bouncing rather than the odd spinning.

Comment: Particles do not simulate as rigid bodies, even if the rendered ('rendered', not 'simulated') objects are rigid bodies and that's not what @LaserLars meant. He was talking about using rigid bodies instead of particles. However, of course you can stop the particle simulation at a certain point, convert the particles, and make them rigid bodies. But then the rigid body simulation starts new, the objects do not inherit any movement from the particles.